# displaying the function result on a menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if it's possible to display value returned from a function on the Main Menu in WordPress? I figured I can use custom links to display text on the menu. Now I would like call a function which calculates the number of users online and display the result on the menu.

Something like `chinesepod.com` does

Here's the code for calculating the number of users : -

```
function ray_number_online_users() {
     $i = 0;

     if ( bp_has_members( ‘user_id=0&type=online&per_page=999&populate_extras=0′ ) ) :

       while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member();
           $i++;

       endwhile;   

     endif;

    return $i;
 }`
```

Comment: Do you want it after a link as in (Link (number of users) ), or does it need to be a seperate link sa in (Home / Other Link / Number of users)?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to be a part of the link  something like "members online : --insert value--" to be a link . But either way is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to target a single link on your menu is by giving it a [class](http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item) (user-number in this case).

The theme location is defined by the register_nav_menus function

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu',      'twentyfifteen' ),
        'social'  => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    ) );
```

Here I target the `primary` menu location, but I could also target the `social` menu.

```
function so30559666_nav_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    if ( 'primary' == $args->theme_location && in_array("user-number", $item->classes)) {
        $count = ray_number_online_users();
        $item_output = str_replace( $args->link_after . '</a>', '<div class="menu-user-count">' . $count . '</div>' . $args->link_after . '</a>', $item_output );
    }

    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'so30559666_nav_description', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Works great thanks. However the count value is now pushed to the next line. How can I make appear in one single line?

Comment: You can style the div as inline. Or just remove the div surrounding the $count.